# Warning preg_match(), mysqli_query() getting error in codeigniter on xampp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am running script which fetch orders from website and insert in database its working fine but i am getting this error each time script runs-

> ERROR - Severity: Warning  --> preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be
> string, object given
> C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php 202
>
> ERROR - Severity: Warning  --> mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to
> be string, object given
> C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_driver.php 179
>
> ERROR - Severity: Warning  --> preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be
> string, object given C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php 622
>
> ERROR - Severity: Warning  --> mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1
> to be mysqli_result, null given
> C:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\drivers\mysqli\mysqli_result.php 37

This is my code below

```
   public function insert_orders($data_orders) {

    foreach($data_orders as $key=>$value){
        $order_id=trim($value['order_id']);
        $amount_paid=trim($value['amount_paid']);
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id='".$order_id."' AND amount_paid LIKE '".$amount_paid."'");
            if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
          unset($data_orders[$key]);
            }
        }


if(count($data_orders)==0) return;

$this->db->insert_batch('orders', $data_orders);


    }
```

I cannot see any issue with this but can you please check and let me know where i am making mistake?

I am using codeigniter.

Database setting -

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Check the two variables $order_id and $amount_paid have values?

Comment: Yes, It showing both values

Comment: can you `var_dump($data_orders)` in your question..?

Comment: Showing all orders in array correctly.

Comment: try setting `$config['log_threshold'] = 3;` in your config.php and see the full log.. that may help you to solve the issue..

Comment: At the moment i set 4, Ok i will set 3 and see

Comment: Got the same message

Comment: also capture $this->db->last_query() after your batch insert call and see what is being sent. Is anything being inserted?

Comment: Yes, it insterting the data but My questions in why it showing this error because of big data?

Comment: Please use **Transaction** for large no of query. [https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html#transactions)

Answer (score 0):

make `num_rows` to `num_rows()`

like this

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
```

Comment: nop same error again.I have update the question with my database setting.

Comment: $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id=".$order_id." AND amount_paid LIKE ".$amount_paid);

Comment: Nop same message. I tried everything but same error

Comment: This answer is correct. Check the docs the CI active record num_rows() is a function it needs brackets at the end.

Comment: I am using Brackets - if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
          unset($data_orders[$key]);
            }